# Get Angular scope variable length

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to get the length of Angular model `$scope`. My code alerts `undefined`.
But `scope` has a value when I alert `scope` without `length`

```
alert($scope.comppostal.length)
```

How to check the length? Content of `$scope.comppostal` is `12345`

Comment: Can you post content of `$scope.comppostal`?

Comment: its working when i errase  the value and re-enter

Comment: @Ervikas. Thats a number. How can you use `.length` for a number?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are getting the `undefined` as `$scope.comppostal` is a number. You need to convert it to string.

*Use*

```
alert((''+$scope.comppostal).length)
```

```js
var a = 12345;
alert(('' + a).length);
```

Comment: is this  ' ' effect on my length

Comment: @Ervikas, `''` is empty string, hence no impact